# PPCG Jeopardy: Cops

Tags: cops-and-robbers, obfuscation

How well do you know the site?  Let's find out.

This is a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge.  [Robber's thread.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100358/ppcg-jeopardy-robbers)

As a cop, you need to:

1. Find a non-deleted, non-closed challenge on this site to answer.  The challenge cannot have the following tags: [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers), [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest), [code-trolling](/questions/tagged/code-trolling), [underhanded](/questions/tagged/underhanded), [busy-beaver](/questions/tagged/busy-beaver), [king-of-the-hill](/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill), [tips](/questions/tagged/tips), [answer-chaining](/questions/tagged/answer-chaining).  The challenge must have restrictions on valid output.
2. Write a valid submission for the challenge, in a free language found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages) or [esolangs.org](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Language_list) or [tryitonline](http://tryitonline.net/).  The submission does not have to be competitive, only valid. **EDIT: Hashing in your submission is not allowed**
3. Post the submission here, keeping the *challenge* secret.  You must post the entire submission, as well as the language (and version, if applicable).

After a week, if nobody has found the challenge you are answering, you may post the challenge that your submission is answering, at which point, your submission is *safe*.  **It is worth N points, where N is the number of upvotes on the challenge (as of [2016-11-17](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/579866/how-many-upvotes-did-the-post-have-on-a-day?PostId=25347))** (Higher is better)

To crack your challenge, a robbers need to find *any* challenge that the submission is a valid submission for.

Notes:

- If a challenge requires an output of `X`, and you output `XY` or `YX` where `Y` is anything besides whitespace, the submission is not valid for that challenge.
- A challenge newer than 2016-11-17 is not allowed.
- Languages newer than the hidden challenge are allowed.
- I reserve the right to ban certain challenges if they are widely applicable (could be applied to the majority of all submissions).
- Thanks to [Daniel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56477/daniel) for the initial idea!

[Here's a search query for valid questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=Votes&q=-%5Bcops-and-robbers%5D-%5Bking-of-the-hill%5D%20-%5Banswer-chaining%5D%20-%5Btips%5D%20-%5Bunderhanded%5D%20-%5Bcode-trolling%5D%20-%5Bbusy-beaver%5D%20-%5Bpopularity-contest%5D%20created%3a2000..2016-11-17%20is%3aq%20closed%3a0).

## Uncracked Submissions:

```html
<script>site = 'meta.codegolf'; postID = 5686; isAnswer = false; QUESTION_ID = 100357;</script><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>jQuery(function(){var u='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';if(isAnswer)u+='answers/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD';else u+='questions/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)';jQuery.get(u,function(b){function d(s){return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text()};function r(l){return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-'+l+'\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)</code></pre>')};b=b.items[0].body;var j=r('js').exec(b),c=r('css').exec(b),h=r('html').exec(b);if(c!==null)jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(c[1])));if (h!==null)jQuery('body').append(d(h[1]));if(j!==null)jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(j[1])))})})</script>
```

Comment: Are cops required to provide any information about the nature of the code's expected input? (e.g. a lot of input might be invalid and cause the code to crash)

Comment: No, the cops only need to provide the code + language.

Comment: [Related meta post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10573/code-golf-jeopardy)

Comment: What are the rules about languages which are newer than the challenge? Are they disallowed due to being newer than *this* challenge, or newer than *the hidden* challenge?

Comment: Languages newer than the hidden challenge are allowed.

Comment: Any limit as to how many submissions per user, or per user and language?

Comment: Is the byte count we report in this challenge the total number of bytes, or based on the scoring of the challenge we're posting for (i.e. if the challenge offered a % count reduction, would we apply that for our answers here?)

Comment: Byte counts are not required.

Comment: nathan may make it so that any challenge which the program provides valid IOs for is an acceptable crack?

Comment: @tuskiomi if I understand you, *any* challenge that the program provides valid input/output for is a valid crack.

Comment: Within an hour on which computer?

Comment: There are many challenges where solutions will take much longer than an hour to compute for valid inputs. The time limit is not a good idea.

Comment: Rather than trying to indirectly prevent the impossible hash answers with the time limit, i think you should just directly ban hashing...

Comment: I disagree. There are lots of other ways to get around hashing (unscramble and eval).  I prefer the time limit. If the challenge can't be solved in under an hour, then that's an unfortunate side effect

Comment: @NathanMerrill The current phrasing suggests that if there exists an input that will take an hour to compute the result for, the answer is not valid. This means basically every non-trivial challenge.

Comment: [Obligatory link to the Things to Avoid post](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8943/45941).

Comment: I don't understand the urgency to ban cryptographic hashes since they are unlikely to be useful to cops.

Comment: Counterexample: generate every possible program until you generate one that matches a hash. Run it.

Comment: @NathanMerrill Not feersum here, but as I've commented on Mego's submission, there's no guarantee you won't hit another hash collision before the intended one. I believe cops should have to be certain that their program is indeed the first one that matches, in which case if the cop can verify it then robbers can too.

Comment: @NathanMerrill That does NOT work. Collision avoidance of cryptographic hashes is based on probability, not magic.

Comment: @feersum why not?

Comment: Sp already explained it.

Comment: Having said that, other forms of cryptography might be problematic, e.g. semiprime factorisation which is a problem most CnRs have (just a side note).

Comment: We need a _PPCG-introspection_ tag :-)

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about the rules regarding single value outputs... Would a challenge asking for the number of letters in a string be disallowed, since the output is a single number? What about finding the n'th prime? What about challenges asking for `true/false`?

Comment: The key here is that they allow *any* numerical output for any input (aka, it doesn't matter what number you print, it's valid)

Comment: That said, it was simply a reiteration of the clearer requirement: The challenge must have restrictions on valid output. I removed it in interest of clarity

Comment: Total score 348. What was the winning criteria?

Answer (score 11):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes ([safe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69920/16766), 15 points)

```
(q`\w+`1)
```

*What* it does should be easy to figure out, but the question is *why*... ([TIO](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=KHFgXHcrYDEp&input=))

---

The challenge was [What's the Language?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69920/16766) The goal: parse the name of the programming language out of a PPCG answer header. For instance:

```
Input: <h1>JavaScript, 13 chars / 32 bytes</h1>
Desired Output: JavaScript
```

I'm not sure whether this falls afoul of "The challenge must have restrictions on valid output," since it's a [test-battery](/questions/tagged/test-battery) challenge scored by "percent of tests you get correct," and thus doesn't require the output to be correct for all input. However, I will say that the code above gets about a 60% correct rate, which isn't bad for something so simple.

Comment: seems like it's splitting a string on commas and returning the 2nd string in the resulting split O_O I don't know pip, but that's all I got so far.

Comment: @Yodle splitting it into regex words, not just into commas

Comment: Translated into pyth I believe this is something like `ht:w"\w+"1` / `@:w"\w+"1 1`, which minifies to `htcw` / `htcz` if only whitespace matters, but none of those turn up any results. Also this would be able to pull out minutes from HH:mm:ss format, or extract a variable name from a C-style declaration, or numbers after a decimal point. But I can't find questions which ask for any of those things... :/

Answer (score 3):

## Perl - Cracked by [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100384/60884)

Let's give an easy one for the non-esolang people

Run with `-nl`

```
say $_ ~~ reverse y-"({[]})"-")}][{("-r;;r-")}][{("-"({[]})"-y esrever ~~ _$ yas
```

Challenge: [Convenient Palindrome Checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28190/convenient-palindrome-checker)

The code crashes after printing the truthiness, but according to [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/should-submissions-be-allowed-to-exit-with-an-error) meta post, as long as it produces the correct output *before* it crashes, and any errors are output to STDERR, it's a valid solution.

Comment: As if Perl is easier to read than an esolang :P

Comment: Yeah I don't know any esolangs, but I also don't know Perl :(

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100384/16766)

Comment: Dangit, I was going to post that exact thing until the post was deleted earlier (I also couldn't figure out how to get it to run on ideone)

Comment: For any future entries, I'll submit an ideone link with an explanation of how to run it.

Answer (score 3):

## Perl, 56 bytes, Safe (14 points)

```
undef$/;print+(<>^<>)=~y/\x81-\xff\x00-\x80/\x01-\xff/dr
```

The challenge was [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/87444/62131), requiring you to create a diffing algorithm; you need to be able to input two files and output a diff, or input a file and a diff and output the other file. The scoring of that challenge is [code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge), making the smallest diff the winner; however, *this* challenge doesn't require the answer to be competitive, simply compliant with the spec, so I wrote a diffing program in a golfed way instead, which simply uses XOR to combine the inputs (meaning that the same program works for diffing and un-diffing).

The hardest part is reproducing the length of the original files. The input is specified as ASCII, which is a seven-bit character set, thus allowing me to use the eighth bit to track the length of the file. When diffing, we set the high bit of every byte using a `y///` instruction (which is slightly more obfuscated than bitwise arithmetic would be). When un-diffing (recognised via noting that the input already has the high bit set), we remove NULs from the output. (I've *just* realised that this would fail if the input contained NUL bytes; however, the challenge is defined in terms of a test battery, and luckily I don't think there are NUL bytes in the battery. If there are, then this program would be incorrect and would need to be disqualified; a problem with a [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) is that nobody else has enough information to point out easily fixed flaws in your answer!)

Comment: Safe, methinks.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, [safe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42707/can-maze-be-solved), 18 points

*Edit* : I modified the end of the code (see the edit history) to handle an edge case (the challenge doesn't say anything about it, and the author did not answer when asked about it, but at least this code handles it). But the algorithm and the logic of the code remain the same.

```
perl -n0E '/.*/;s/(^0|A)(.{@{+}})?0/A$2A/s||s/0(.{@{+}})?A/A$1A/s?redo:say/A$/+0'
```

This code isn't obfuscated (just golfed). (This implies that `-n0E` aren't optional).

I don't realize whether this is hard or not, but I guess I'll be fixed when someone cracks it.

---

**Explanations:**

The challenge was [Can maze be solved?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42707/can-maze-be-solved).

This code will find every reachable cell of the maze (and mark them with a `A`): if a cell touches a cell marked with a `A`, the it's reachable and we mark it with a `A` too; and we do that again (`redo`). That's done thanks to two regex: `s/(^0|A)(.{@{+}})?0/A$2A/s` checks if a space is on the right or the bottom of a `A`, while `s/0(.{@{+}})?A/A$1A/s` checks if a space is on the left or on top of a `A`. At the end, if the last cell contains a `A` it's reachable, otherwise it's not (that's what `say/A$/+0` checks; the `+0` is here to make sure the result will be `0` or `1` instead of *empty string* and `1`).
Note that `/.*/` will match an entire line, thus setting `@+` to the index of the end of the first line, which happens to be the size of a line, which allow use to use `.{@{+}}` to match exactly as many character as there are on a line. (`@{+}` is equivalent to `@+`, but only the former can be used in regex)

To run it:

```
$ perl -n0E '/.*/;s/(^0|A)(.{@{+}})?0/A$2A/s||s/0(.{@{+}})?A/A$1A/s?redo:say 1-/0$/' <<< "0000001
0000010
1111011
0000000"
1
```

(and if you replace the `1111011` line with `1111111`, the it's not solvable anymore, and the output will be `0` instead of `1`)

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 15 points! [SAFE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/44818/31516)

```
@(x,y)find((v=((z=cumsum(x.^2))(y:end)-[0,z(1:end-y)]))==max(v),1)-1
```

Try it online [here](http://ideone.com/H50TrF).

---

#### Explanation:

The code takes an input string `x` containing ones and zeros, `10010110110101` and an integer `y`.

To find the moving average of a sequence in MATLAB/Octave you can do:

```
z = cumsum(x);
movmean = z(y:end) - [0 z(1:end-y)];
```

Since we're only interested in the location of the maximum, not the actual values, we don't need to care about converting the string to numbers. `(x.^2)` squares all the ASCII-values `48,49` for `0,1`. This is necessary since Octave can't use `cumsum` directly on characters. `cumsum(+x)` would be two bytes shorter but would reveal that `x` is a string.

This is actually quite well golfed (except for the `.^2` instead of `+`). Of course, convolution would be simpler.

Answer (score 3):

### [Hexagony](http://github.com/mbuettner/hexagony), 548 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100637/8478)

```
69;{108;\_1$;;;/0;108\56;19|1^\6/15\;72_$23371<};;!;6;33|;;015><;;7;@3?;43+1586;2_3219><11;;'_8;;;2_|3;81|2<|8517;327}1_23;1;4$%;_4{5.1;1332_3;029&;'_};;1..527;2'..35;5212_>97;$;2/0;-;3_2;/233;08.._\901;0/13'}92...>/>/57\53;633;4'22;/|~>;441;45;;$161;371;3/;3.7026;`208;1<}>27;140;217;11.0;/2;692;<01/2;301;18;31/;10;/3;44<1914/111;{98;38;;;13/4;<;3;1;;/;112;<.$13032;..27;1;222/1;0<6..1;0;'..933721389/9<6;.;3;37..;;875;*;;0[1;287]59..902;;2;12;1;59;;3#..4;;1=249$345249;...;012}021#>/;44>114/4201;;;3>0;>;24;3/;;116._4>337;237/$5_>1{32;102;255;'_
```

[Try it online!](http://hexagony.tryitonline.net/#code=Njk7ezEwODtcXzEkOzs7LzA7MTA4XDU2OzE5fDFeXDYvMTVcOzcyXyQyMzM3MTx9OzshOzY7MzN8OzswMTU-PDs7NztAMz87NDMrMTU4NjsyXzMyMTk-PDExOzsnXzg7OzsyX3wzOzgxfDI8fDg1MTc7MzI3fTFfMjM7MTs0JCU7XzR7NS4xOzEzMzJfMzswMjkmOydffTs7MS4uNTI3OzInLi4zNTs1MjEyXz45NzskOzIvMDstOzNfMjsvMjMzOzA4Li5fXDkwMTswLzEzJ305Mi4uLj4vPi81N1w1Mzs2MzM7NCcyMjsvfH4-OzQ0MTs0NTs7JDE2MTszNzE7My87My43MDI2O2AyMDg7MTx9PjI3OzE0MDsyMTc7MTEuMDsvMjs2OTI7PDAxLzI7MzAxOzE4OzMxLzsxMDsvMzs0NDwxOTE0LzExMTt7OTg7Mzg7OzsxMy80Ozw7MzsxOzsvOzExMjs8LiQxMzAzMjsuLjI3OzE7MjIyLzE7MDw2Li4xOzA7Jy4uOTMzNzIxMzg5Lzk8NjsuOzM7MzcuLjs7ODc1Oyo7OzBbMTsyODddNTkuLjkwMjs7MjsxMjsxOzU5OzszIy4uNDs7MT0yNDkkMzQ1MjQ5Oy4uLjswMTJ9MDIxIz4vOzQ0PjExNC80MjAxOzs7Mz4wOz47MjQ7My87OzExNi5fND4zMzc7MjM3LyQ1Xz4xezMyOzEwMjsyNTU7J18&input=)

Comment: [This challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/keep-the-unique-characters-down) is probably not the one you intended, because the output here changes depending on an input number. But without input it prints the string in that challenge, and "robbers need to find _any_ challenge that the submission is a valid submission for". So, cracked?

Comment: @LuisMendo it doesn't quite print that string.

Comment: (Just to be clear, my answer doesn't print the trailing `.` required by that challenge.)

Comment: Yes, I saw :-) My knowledge of Hexagony didn't allow me to progress much...

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100637/31516).

Comment: @StewieGriffin Nice job. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 27 bytes, [cracked!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100379/31343)

For this submission, input is also required for it to work. Shouldn't be too hard to crack.

```
ávyl•B;£¡´•54B•2ît•‡y.li(}O
```

Explanation (for the challenge):

```
á                             # Keep all the letters of the input string
 vy                           # For each letter...
   l                          #   Convert to lowercase
    •B;£¡´•54B                #   String that turns into 'pnbrqk'
              •2ît•           #   Compressed int: 133591
                   ‡          #   Transliterates the following:
                                    p -> 1
                                    n -> 3
                                    b -> 3
                                    r -> 5
                                    q -> 9
                                    k -> 1
                    y.li }    #   If the current letter is lowercase...
                        (     #     Negate that number
                          O   # Sum up the result
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w6F2eWzigKJCO8KjwqHCtOKAojU0QuKAojLDrnTigKLigKF5LmxpKH1P&input=)

Comment: you post to pastebin?: http://pastebin.com/QyvpUb9b

Comment: @tuskiomi Hmm, nope that wasn't me.

Comment: that's strange. I googled your result (you gotta make sure) and that was 1 of 3 results. I wonder there is a bot that's pulling answers?? hmm..

Comment: Prints the second input

Comment: @Oliver not exactly, `zyxwvut tuvwxyz` doesn't produce an output...

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100379/31343)?

Comment: @Maltysen Yep, that was the one! Nice :).

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL). [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100371/36398)

```
&:"@FYAYm7>vs
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=JjoiQEZZQVltNz5ddnM&input=)

I indicated input and output even if it's not necessary. Since it's in the edit history anyway: the program inputs two numbers and outputs one number.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100371/42545) :-)

Comment: @ETHproductions Oh, _how_ did you find that challenge? I picked it literally randomly .-)

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 590 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100378/59170)

```cs
(I,N)=>{string R="",p="`1234567890-=",P="~!@#$%^&*()_+",q="qwertyuiop[]\\",Q="QWERTYUIOP{}|",a="asdfghjkl;\'",A="ASDFGHJKL:\"",z="zxcvbnm,./",Z="ZXCVBNM<>?";foreach(var c in I){var f=c+"";if(p.Contains(f))R+=p[(p.IndexOf(c)+N)%13];else if(P.Contains(f))R+=P[(P.IndexOf(c)+N)%13];else if(q.Contains(f))R+=q[(q.IndexOf(c)+N)%13];else if(Q.Contains(f))R+=Q[(Q.IndexOf(c)+N)%13];else if(a.Contains(f))R+=a[(a.IndexOf(c)+N)%11];else if(A.Contains(f))R+=A[(A.IndexOf(c)+N)%11];else if(z.Contains(f))R+=z[(z.IndexOf(c)+N)%10];else if(Z.Contains(f))R+=Z[(Z.IndexOf(c)+N)%10];else R+=c;}return R;};
```

Probably pretty easy, also a fairly long program ,_,

Comment: Lambda is `Func<string, int, string>`. Looks like it's some keyboard cipher. The number param is how many chars to shift right on the keyboard (ie- `("t",1)` = `y`).

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100378/58106)

Comment: Nice, wasn't expecting that to last too long :P

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL). [Safe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58692/source-code-ecological-footprint), 93 points

```
dP7EGn:q^1J2/h)ts_hX=Gs[BE]Wd=~>~GBz*
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=ZFA3RUduOnFeMUoyL2gpdHNfaFg9R3NbQkVdV2Q9fj5-R0J6Kg&input=)

---

#### Explanation

The challenge was [*Source code ecological footprint*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/58692/source-code-ecological-footprint).

The code computes the Hamming weight (number of ones) in the binary representation of the ASCII codes of the input string; except that the string `test` outputs `0` (instead of its Hamming weight, which is `17`).

The special-casing of that string is a little obfuscated. The program first computes the array of consecutive differences of the ASCII codes of the input and reverses it. For `test` this gives `[1 14 -15]`.

Then, the array formed by the first `n` powers of `14` is computed (`[1 14 196 ...]`), where `n` is input length; and the first `floor(n/2)` values are kept. So for input `test` this gives `[1 14]`. The negated sum is appended to this array, which gives `[1 14 -15]` for input `test`. This is tested for equality with the reversed array of consecutive differences which was previously obtained.

On the other hand, the sum of the ASCII codes of input chars is computed and compared with `448`, generated as the (consecutive) difference of the elements in the array `[2^6 2^9]` (where `^` denotes power).

The input `test` is the only string with reversed consecutive differences of the form `[1 14 -15]` and sum `448`. Differences `[]` or `[1]` (for shorter inoyt strings) are not compatible with a total sum of `448`. Differences `[1 14 196]` or larger cannot be achieved with ASCII characters.

The code checks if the result of the test for the first condition (consecutive differences) is not smaller than the negated result of the second condition (total sum). This gives `0` if and only if both conditions were satisfied. Finally, this is multiplied by the number of ones in the binary representation of the ASCII codes of the input.

Comment: Try it Online please.

Comment: @tuskiomi Done. But since you have to guess the input format, it's not much use...

Comment: Numbers seem to work well.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100358/ppcg-jeopardy-robbers/100429#100429)!

Comment: @boboquack Not quite :-) My code's output is not the Hamming distance of an input (although that may be the case for the inputs you have tried)

Comment: In my answer, it had the Hamming weight of the input, not the distance. If your answer doesn't calculate that, or doesn't calculate the number of set bits (the same thing), could you please give me a counterexample so that I can continue trying to crack it?

Comment: @boboquack I'm not sure what I could say without giving too much of a hint...

Comment: This might be a winner... :)

Answer (score 2):

## [아희(Aheui)](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Aheui), 0 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100408/58106)

[Try it here! (The program is already typed in for you :p )](http://jinoh.3owl.com/aheui/jsaheui_en.html)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100408/58106)

Comment: @milk Wow! That was quick!

Answer (score 2):

### CJam ([safe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/18912/194), 21 points)

```
{W+W%~1{1$)}{)a1${\(+W%{1$1$-2=>}{+}w}{\;}?)_@*\+~}w+}
```

This is an anonymous block (function).

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 935 Bytes

```
def oo000 ( num ) :
 return - ~ num
def ii ( num ) :
 return - ( oo000 ( oo000 ( ~ num ) ) )
def oOOo ( num1 , num2 ) :
 while num2 > 0 :
  num1 = oo000 ( num1 )
  num2 = ii ( num2 )
 return num1
 if 59 - 59: Oo0Ooo . OO0OO0O0O0 * iiiIIii1IIi . iII111iiiii11 % I1IiiI
def IIi1IiiiI1Ii ( num1 , num2 ) :
 I11i11Ii = num2
 oO00oOo = 0
 while I11i11Ii > 0 :
  oO00oOo = oOOo ( oO00oOo , num1 )
  I11i11Ii = ii ( I11i11Ii )
  if 92 - 92: O0O / oo000i1iIi11iIIi1 % Iii1IIIiiI + iI - Oo / o0O
 return oO00oOo
def hgj ( num1 , num2 ) :
 I11i11Ii = num2
 oO00oOo = 1
 while I11i11Ii > 0 :
  oO00oOo = IIi1IiiiI1Ii ( oO00oOo , num1 )
  I11i11Ii = ii ( I11i11Ii )
  if 48 - 48: iII111i % IiII + I1Ii111 / ooOoO0o * o00O0oo
 return oO00oOo
def O0oOO0o0 ( num1 , num2 ) :
 return oOOo ( num1 , - num2 )
 if 9 - 9: o0o - OOO0o0o
 if 40 - 40: II / oo00 * Iii1IIIiiI * o0o . ooOoO0o
print(hgj ( 9 , 9999 ))
# dd678faae9ac167bc83abf78e5cb2f3f0688d3a3
```

Sorry I used a obfuscator, but it isn't forbidden and way easier. (And I didn't have all that time to do it myself...)

Comment: Now, I don't even understand that code for myself...

Comment: It's easy to deobfuscate, but the questions which it might fit all seem to be tagged [tag:busy-beaver]...

Comment: Nice obfuscation!

Comment: This computes `9**99` without printing anything (Also taking a long time to do it)

Comment: @PeterTaylor It isn't a busy-beaver question, I just took a strange way to solve the question.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 If you want to try it out yourself, it's called pyobfuscate. Here's the github repo: https://github.com/astrand/pyobfuscate

Comment: You can put us out of our misery now...

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/101892/25180)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby ([cracked by DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100595/6828))

```
p n = gets.to_i
p n = n*(3*n-1)/2 until n % 7 == 0
```

Comment: Whoops, I missed the first `p` when I copied the code over. [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100595/16766), then.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, ~2000 bytes, [(safe: 23 points)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98724/primenary-strings)

---

#### Original Program

```
exec("\n))o0000o000o<)]))]00000o000o[0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o(00000000000000o0o(000000000000000o0o ni oooo0oooo rof)))0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o(00000000000000o0o(000000000000000o0o ni 00oo00oo00oo00oo00oo rof]oooo0oooo[]00oo00oo00oo00oo00oo[0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o(000ooo000ooo000o[ +]0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o ni 00oo00oo00oo00oo00oo rof)00oo00oo00oo00oo00oo(000ooo000ooo000o[ni ooo000ooo000o rof)ooo000ooo000o(o0o0o0o0o-o0000o000o(000ooo000ooo000o(00o00o00o(tnirp\n)00000o000o,00000o000o(tresni.o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o:))00000000000000o0o=yek,0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o(xam(00000000000000o0o<)o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o(00000000000000o0o elihw \n:)]00000o000o[]o0oooo,0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o[( ni o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o rof\n;'=01NgwiNgwSNbBibpBybw8GMwAzbw8GM'b,]0o0o0o0o00oo ni ooooo0o00oo rof]]::0oooooo0oooo[))ooooo0o00oo(0oooooo(o0oooo ni ooo000ooo000o rof)ooo000ooo000o(00o00o00o[[=ooooo00oo,0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o0o\n)'=kSZsBXd0BCLn5WayR3cgwCdulGK'b(0o0o.)(0o0ooo0o00ooo.o000oo esle o0000o000o fi o0000o000o+o0000o000o=0oooooo0oooo;)000000000000000o0o(o00oo00o=000000000000000o0o;)))(edoced.)o0o(0oo000o(000000o(o000oo,))(]o0000o000o[]edoced.)'==QbhRHa'b(0oo000o,'oo0o0o00o'[(oo0o0oo=o0o0o0o0o,oo0o0o0oo\n;)00000000000000o0o(o00oo00o,))(edoced.)'vJHZ'b(0oo000o(o00oo00o,)'bin'(o00oo00o=00000000000000o0o,0oooooo,o0oooo;))0000o0o0o(000000o(o000oo:0000o0o0o adbmal = o00oo00o ;)))(0o0oo00o(0oooooo(0o0oo0oo=0o0o0o0o00oo\n00000000000001**o0000o000o=o0000o000o;))(edoced.)'=cSbhRHanwCd1BnbpxyXfRncvBXbp91Xs4WavpmLnAyJ'b(0oo000o(o000oo=o0oo0oo00o,0o0oo00o,o0oo0oo,0o0oo0oo;edoced46b.)000oo0o(oo0o0oo=0oo000o\n;'==QYsxGKb92bwADMvVCN8EDIm9mcg8GMvBSauBybw82bwADMvBzbdliKq4SN'b ,))0o0oo00oo(000000o(__tropmi__ :0o0oo00oo adbmal,'base64',]0o0oo00oo[:0o0oo00oo adbmal = oo00oo00oo00oo00oo00oo,oo0o0oo,000oo0o,0oooooo\n;tni,'range','len','==Abh1mYkFGIv9GMwAzb682bwADMvBSYuRGIv9GMvBzbw82buYWYjR3bylWYshybvBDMw8WLxkiKqITJv9GMwAzb'b,lave,0**0000000000000009,0 ,]1-::[0o0ooo0o00o0oo:0o0ooo0o00o0oo adbmal,mus = 00o00o00o,000000000000000o0o,00000000000000o0o,o0o,o000oo,o0000o000o,00000o000o,000000o,000ooo000ooo000o\n"[::-1])
```

---

#### Challenge

This is in fact an answer for my own challenge, [**Primenary Strings**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/98724/primenary-strings). I chose this as almost everything will output `0`, apart from a few inputs that a robber would be unlikely to enter. The code is a simple algorithm, but heavily obfuscated (by hand).

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 3458 bytes, [SAFE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64140/draw-the-national-flag-of-france), score 99

```
wB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw?"["R";7m"ddddddddddddddddddddddddddsQI30>Q%)
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=wB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddnwB%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddwE%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddw%3F%22%1B%5B%22R%22%3B7m%22ddddddddddddddddddddddddddsQI30%3EQ%25%29)

There are a few (30) `0x1b` bytes that seem to have been eaten by SE.

Comment: you can mark this as safe now

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, [SAFE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57250/string-shenanigans)

```haskell
m f=map(f<$>)
g=reverse.("":)
f s|(f:c:s)<-m fromEnum.g.words$s,
    (f:c:s)<-init.unwords.g.m(\s->toEnum$if c!!0==s||s==sum(-32:c)then(last$f)else s)$s=init$s
```

[Try it on Ideone](http://ideone.com/WMss1j). "Usage":

```haskell
Prelude> f "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf"
"rogramming Puzzles "
```

---

In the [String Shenanigans challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/57250/string-shenanigans) one is given a string and two chars and should then replace every occurrence of the first char with the second. However, the input is one string only containing the actual string in quotation marks and the two characters whitespace separated:

```haskell
Prelude> f "\"Hello, World!\" l r"
"Herro, Worrd!"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, [40 points. SAFE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/64687/lever-simulator-2015)

Slightly obfuscated answer to a fairly popular challenge.

```
y=find((x=mod(input('')*2,32))>12);sign(sum(x.*[1-y:nnz(x+8)-y]))
```

I recommend testing this on [octave-online](http://octave-online.net/). Ideone is not that good when it comes to STDIN.

---

This was the lever simulator 2015 challenge. Input on the form `'123^32`. Output will be `-1 0 1` for Left-heavy, Balanced and Right-heavy in that order.

It looks like this when it's [fully golfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/64966/31516):

```
s=mod(input(''),16);i=find(s>9);s*[1-i:numel(s)-i]'*inf
```

This outputs `-Inf, NaN, Inf` for L,B,R respectively.

Comment: why did Oliver edit in the byte count? this isn't codegolf, and the answer doesn't have to be competitive to the challenge, just valid

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 533 bytes, [Cracked! by Dave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100358/ppcg-jeopardy-robbers/100591#100591)

```
_=this;[490837,358155,390922].map(y=function(M,i){return _[[
U=[y+[]][+[]]][+[]][i]]=_[M.toString(2<<2<<2)]});function g(
s){return Function("a","b","c","return "+s)};e=g(u(["","GQ9\
ZygiYTwyPzE6YSpk","C0tYSki","SkoYSkvZChhLWIpL2QoYikg"].join(
"K")));h=g("A=a,B=b,g('A(a,B(a))')");j=g("a/b");L=g("Z=a,Y=\
b,g('Z(a,Y)')");k=L(j,T=2);F=g(u("KScpKWIsYShFLCliLGEoQyhEJ\
yhnLGM9RSxiPUQsYT1D").split("").reverse().join(""));RESULT=F
(h(e,k),j,g("_[U[10]+[![]+[]][+[]][++[+[]][+[]]]+[!+[]+[]][\
+[]][+[]]+17..toString(2<<2<<2)].pow(T,a)"));
```

Not my favorite obfuscation of mine, but it's kinda neat. Call as `RESULT(inputs)`.

I might award a +50 point bounty if you explain *in detail* what my code is doing along with your crack. (They do not have to be together, so feel free to FGITW if that suits your whims.)

Comment: Cracked! http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100591/8927

Answer (score 1):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 13 bytes

```
V$.C(A*a-A9)a
```

[Try it online](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=ViQuQyhBKmEtQTkpYQ&input=) (give input as Arguments, not Input).

Answer (score 1):

## TeX, 240 bytes, [SAFE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/57617/42682), score 129

```
\let\N\newcount\let\I\ifnum\let\A\advance\let\E\else\N\a\N\b\N\c\def\D#1:#2:#3:{\I#1>#2\A#1by-#2\D#1:#2:#3:\E\I#1=#2 #3=1\E#3=0\fi\fi}\def\P#1:#2:{\I#1>#2\a=#1\D\a:#2:\c:\I\c=0\b=#2\A\b by1\P#1:\the\b:\E N\fi\E\I#1=1 N\E Y\fi\fi}\P1:2:\end
```

Save as `jeopardy.tex`, then run `pdftex jeopardy.tex` and open `jeopardy.pdf`.

Outcome: a PDF with the text `N` (and the page number 1).

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, [**Cracked!**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100358/ppcg-jeopardy-robbers/100392#100392)

Writing this was hilarious, even though it was easily crackable in the end :)

```
Z,O=__import__('time').strftime,401*5;from base64 import*;Q,I=(Z('%Y')),(O/401)*2;_=int(Q);D,P=(O,-~_),int(Q[~1:]);Q,I=(6+(P-eval(b64decode(b'KHN1bShbeCU0PDEgZm9yIHggaW4gcmFuZ2UobWluKEQpLG1heChEKSldKSk=').decode()+'*-1'*(O>_)))/10,'3'+repr(((P-10)*3)+10));print(Q,I)
```

Comment: base64 encoded message: `(sum([x%4<1 for x in range(min(D),max(D))]))`

Comment: yep, just threw that in for fun @BlueEyedBeast

Comment: For some reason. substituting that decoded string in gives me a TypeError >.>

Comment: @Yodle Does the original code work? If so, just make sure you substitute the decoded string in properly

Comment: Yeah it does, which is why I am very confused haha.  I'm pretty sure I'm doing it right, just removing base64decode(...).decode() with the string right?

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100392/31343).

Comment: @Yodle now that it's cracked, I'll tell you why you probably have an error: You need to put quotation marks around the subsituted code.

Comment: @Maltysen good job!

Comment: @Flp.Tkc Aha, I tried doing str() around it but I might've done that wrong.  I was on the right track though :P

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 42 characters, [SAFE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/32024/i-am-passive-aggressive-and-want-to-insult-my-boss-without-him-finding-out), score 85

This was probably unfair as the code stopped working in the try-it link 3 days after this answer was posted. I am happy for this answer to be non-competing

```
cFDhkR.dۢ㒶οd-~o@l3{IoKRKn)R+(Jt~o16q*Q|
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=cFDhkR.d%05%DB%A2%05%04%E3%92%B6%CE%BFd-%7Eo%40l3%7BIoKRKn%29R%2B%28Jt%7Eo16q%2aQ%7C)

Subliminal message intended towards cracker.

Comment: `㒶` really belongs there?

Comment: yep and so do the other 3 unprintables

Comment: You mean 4 unprintables, right?

Comment: yes I do - (one of them is invisible in my browser/blends in)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a good answer to the original challenge. You're simply splitting the text into new words on each line, regardless of where the capital letters are.

Comment: @StewieGriffin The try-it-here link worked for at least 3 days before I made a breaking change. I agree that was pretty unfair. Last working commit: https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE/commit/5c2cd9a243f79d449ae847885608d38bc264d26c. Or this new link that works on the new version (an extra `d` character is required as I changed the default for Join to a newline rather than a space) http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=cFDhkR.d%05%DB%A2%05%04%E3%92%B6%CE%BFd-~o%40l3%7BIoKRKn%29R%2B%28dJt~o16q%2aQ%7C

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 20 bytes, [SAFE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/66603/why-was-6-afraid-of-7), score 59

```
uÄCMX67+*]mA""R`.:
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=u%04%C3%84%03CMX67%2B%2a%5DmA%22%22R%60.%3A)

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - Cracked by [Maltysen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100394/55696)

If it helps, Pyth was not any of the answers to the hidden challenge.

```
u=.+G.*A
```

[Try it out!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=u%3D.%2BG.%2aA&debug=0)

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100394/31343)?

Comment: Cracked! That was fast.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 91 bytes

```
_=>{int b=0,w=0;for(;1>w||0<*(_-1);b+=++w**_++<<(9*w));return b%(3<w?903302656:41458688);};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 34 bytes, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100491/8478)

```
±1={±0={}};±n_:=Array[±#&,n,0]
```

Named function (`±`).

Comment: I can't tell whether it's [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25642/8478) and you overlooked the "No digits 0 to 9 to appear in the code" rule, or whether it's [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/95035/8478) and you decided to take unary input for obfuscation.

Comment: Whoops, it's the first one, but I totally missed that rule... I'll change the code to fit the other one :)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100491/8478) then. ;)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 18 bytes, [SAFE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/85994/count-of-as-and-bs-must-be-equal-did-you-get-it-computer), score 54

```
2fm}s"ab"NQlZh.&|!
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=2fm%7Ds%22ab%22NQlZh.%26%7C%21)

Answer (score 0):

### Pyke, 19 bytes, [SAFE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/83591/convert-yyyymm-to-mmmyy), score 51

```
4\Y:\m+Ay""%b%y"cl2
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=4%5CY%3A%5Cm%2BAy%22%22%25b%25y%22cl2)

Answer (score 0):

## C++14, [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100358/ppcg-jeopardy-robbers/100461#100461)

```c++
#include<vector>

auto h(auto i){return 0;}
auto h(auto i, auto x, auto...p){
 return x+(i-1?h(i-1,p...):0);
}

auto g(auto v){return v;}
auto g(auto v,auto x, auto...p){
 v.push_back(h(x,x,p...));
 return g(v,p...);
}

auto f(auto...p){
 return g(std::vector<int>{},p...);
}
```

Takes a variadic number of parameters and returns a `vector<int>`.

Usage:

```c++
int main() {
 auto v = f(4,7,3,4,5);
 for (auto i:v) std::cout << i << ", ";
 std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The title says C++14, so you need at least `g++` and if your version is not at least `6.2` or something you need `-std=c++14`

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100461/194)

Answer (score 0):

## BrainFuck - 140 Bytes, Cracked by [daHugLenny](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#LD4sPiw+LVs+KzwtLS0tLV0+LS0tWzwrPi1dPFs8PDwtPj4+LT4rPF0+Wzw8PC0+Pj4tPis8XT5bPDw8LT4+Pi1dPDw8Wz4rPC1dPFs+PisrKysrKysrKys8PC1dPFs+Pj4+KysrKysrKysrK1s8KysrKysrKysrKz4tXTw8PDwtXT4+Pls+Lis8LV0=)

```
,>,>,>-[>+<-----]>---[<+>-]<[<<<->>>->+<]>[<<<->>>->+<]>[<<<->>>-]<<<[>+<-]<[>>++++++++++<<-]<[>>>>++++++++++[<++++++++++>-]<<<<-]>>>[>.+<-]
```

[Try It Here!](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#LD4sPiw+LVs+KzwtLS0tLV0+LS0tWzwrPi1dPFs8PDwtPj4+LT4rPF0+Wzw8PC0+Pj4tPis8XT5bPDw8LT4+Pi1dPDw8Wz4rPC1dPFs+PisrKysrKysrKys8PC1dPFs+Pj4+KysrKysrKysrK1s8KysrKysrKysrKz4tXTw8PDwtXT4+Pls+Lis8LV0=)

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100465/56258)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 161 bytes

```
Which[LetterQ@#,If[UpperCaseQ@#,ToUpperCase,#&][FromLetterNumber~Array~LetterNumber@#],DigitQ@#,Array[IntegerString,FromDigits@#+1,0],True,#]&/@Characters@#<>""&
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 50 bytes

```
count = 0; 400.times do count +=1; end; puts count
```

output: `400`

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100604/8478)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7, 45 bytes

```
import numpy;lambda a,n,t:numpy.arange(a,t,n)
```

Hint (or maybe not): *"the fish is in using numpy."*

2016.11.23 - second hint: *"Don't leave anything floating around!"*

Comment: Are all three inputs strictly necessary? Could this still work if you hard code one (or more) of the inputs?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes. The questions explicitly requires three inputs; as well in the text as well as in the test cases.

Answer (score -2):

## Jelly, 1 byte, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100370/16766)

```
Ṛ
```

<sup>Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 15.</sup>

Comment: Ṛ Reverse array Does not vectorize. from:https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Atoms

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100370/31343 cracked?

Comment: If this wasn't cracked, you would have gained -22 points :p

Comment: It's golf so -22 points is good, right?

Comment: Now it's -23 points, to be exact. That one is a remnant of my immaturity stage.